# Twilo 6.2.1 Remote Thumbnail Not Available

Tags: android, twilio, video-streaming, webrtc-android

I upgraded my Android application to use Twilio Video SDK v6.2.1 using the migration guide.  The application allows users to communicate via video with people in an office; the office side uses a web application to interact with them.  Since updating the SDK version to 6.2.1 the website no longer shows a thumbnail of the user, but a large 'primary view' is still visible.  (Yes, there should be the large 'main display' and a redundant thumbnail view of the phone user.)

Is there something that should be specified within the Android application to enable the thumbnail on the remote side?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, you have to specify a track name for the remote participant to display a thumbnail.

Using this constructor works:

```
public static LocalVideoTrack create(@NonNull Context context,
                                     boolean enabled,
                                     @NonNull VideoCapturer videoCapturer,
                                     @Nullable VideoFormat videoFormat,
                                     @Nullable String name)
```

This constructor does not (notice the missing parameter, 'name'):

```
public static LocalVideoTrack create(@NonNull Context context,
                                     boolean enabled,
                                     @NonNull VideoCapturer videoCapturer,
                                     @Nullable VideoFormat videoFormat)
```